# How to find local minima of a multivariate function with singularity?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, warning-messages, singularity, fitting, matlab

I am working on a logistic regression problem which requires minimizing a cost function `J[{theta0, theta1, theta2}, X, y]` to find the optimal value for fitting parameter `{theta0, theta1, theta2}`.

`X` is a known `M x 3` matrix of real numbers, and `y` an `M`-dimensional vector.  `M` is the number of sample data points (approx. 300) in the training data set. The definition for `J` is

```
J[θ_, X_, y_] := -(1/Length[y]) (y.Log[h[θ, X]] + (1 - y).Log[1 - h[θ, X]])
```

where

```
h[θ_, X_] := Sigmoid[X.θ];
Sigmoid[z_] := 1/(1 + Exp[-z]);
```

When I try to minimize `J` with `NMinimize` and `FindMinimum`, both fail due to singularity:

```
NMinimize[J[{θ0, θ1, θ2}, X1, y1], {θ0, θ1, θ2}]
(* NMinimize::nnum: The function value Indeterminate is not a number at {θ0, θ1, θ2} = {0.673558,0.659492,0.0861047}. >> *)
```

and

```
FindMinimum[J[{θ0, θ1, θ2}, X1, y1], {θ0, 0}, {θ1, 0}, {θ2, 0}]
(* FindMinimum::nrnum: The function value Indeterminate is not a real number at {θ0, θ1, θ2} = {0.00303682,0.364698,0.342032}. >> *)
```

For comparison, in MATLAB, using `fminunc`, it suffers from `NaN` too

```tex
[theta, cost] = fminunc(@(t)(costFunction(t, X, y)), [0;0;0], optimset('MaxIter', 200));
%Warning: Gradient must be provided for trust-region algorithm; using line-search algorithm instead. 
% In fminunc at 365 
%Error using roots (line 28)
%Input to ROOTS must not contain NaN or Inf.
%<snip>
```

however, setting the [`'GradObj'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/unconstrained-nonlinear-optimization-examples.html) option makes it work:

```tex
[theta, cost] = fminunc(@(t)(costFunction(t, X, y)), [0;0;0], optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 400));    
%Local minimum possible.
%fminunc stopped because the final change in function value relative to 
%its initial value is less than the default value of the function tolerance.    
%<stopping criteria details>

theta    
%theta =    
%  -24.9330
%    0.2044
%    0.1996

cost
% cost = 0.2035
```

Is there a way to tweak *Mathematica* to solve this?  The notebook showing the details is [here](https://github.com/Problemania/MachineLearning/tree/master/LogisticRegression).

#### Edit (follow-up questions)

1. Is `Indeterminate` always an unachievable $+\infty$?
2. Is there a way to do automatic regularization (i.e. adding a regularization term $\lambda || \vec{\beta} ||^2 $ and optimizing $\lambda$) when fitting parameter vector $\vec{\beta}$ for [a binary non-linear logistic regression](https://github.com/Problemania/MachineLearning/tree/master/LogisticRegression) by using some option/setting with `LogitModelFit`?
3. The best fit found with `NMinimize` is `J_min` as 0.203498 and `{\[Beta]0 -> -25.1613, \[Beta]1 -> 0.206232, \[Beta]2 -> 0.201472}` as compared to `J_min` as 0.203506 and `[-24.932998 0.204408 0.199618]` found with Matlab's `fminunc`.  It seems Mathematica wins.  Right?
4. Using `LogitModelFit` on the binary nonlinear logistic regression example, it found a decision boundary with a hole.  Is there any way to control the complexity/topology of the decision boundary (thinking under-fitting and/or over-fitting)?

#### Appendix: complete code

The complete code and data is stored in [Github](https://github.com/Problemania/MachineLearning/tree/master/LogisticRegression).  I intend to keep it for as long as Github allows.

#### Appendix: example data set

(as per comment)

```
34.62365962451697,78.0246928153624,0
30.28671076822607,43.89499752400101,0
35.84740876993872,72.90219802708364,0
60.18259938620976,86.30855209546826,1
79.0327360507101,75.3443764369103,1
45.08327747668339,56.3163717815305,0
61.10666453684766,96.51142588489624,1
75.02474556738889,46.55401354116538,1
76.09878670226257,87.42056971926803,1
84.43281996120035,43.53339331072109,1
95.86155507093572,38.22527805795094,0
75.01365838958247,30.60326323428011,0
82.30705337399482,76.48196330235604,1
69.36458875970939,97.71869196188608,1
39.53833914367223,76.03681085115882,0
53.9710521485623,89.20735013750205,1
69.07014406283025,52.74046973016765,1
67.94685547711617,46.67857410673128,0
70.66150955499435,92.92713789364831,1
76.97878372747498,47.57596364975532,1
67.37202754570876,42.83843832029179,0
89.67677575072079,65.79936592745237,1
50.534788289883,48.85581152764205,0
34.21206097786789,44.20952859866288,0
77.9240914545704,68.9723599933059,1
62.27101367004632,69.95445795447587,1
80.1901807509566,44.82162893218353,1
93.114388797442,38.80067033713209,0
61.83020602312595,50.25610789244621,0
38.78580379679423,64.99568095539578,0
61.379289447425,72.80788731317097,1
85.40451939411645,57.05198397627122,1
52.10797973193984,63.12762376881715,0
52.04540476831827,69.43286012045222,1
40.23689373545111,71.16774802184875,0
54.63510555424817,52.21388588061123,0
33.91550010906887,98.86943574220611,0
64.17698887494485,80.90806058670817,1
74.78925295941542,41.57341522824434,0
34.1836400264419,75.2377203360134,0
83.90239366249155,56.30804621605327,1
51.54772026906181,46.85629026349976,0
94.44336776917852,65.56892160559052,1
82.36875375713919,40.61825515970618,0
51.04775177128865,45.82270145776001,0
62.22267576120188,52.06099194836679,0
77.19303492601364,70.45820000180959,1
97.77159928000232,86.7278223300282,1
62.07306379667647,96.76882412413983,1
91.56497449807442,88.69629254546599,1
79.94481794066932,74.16311935043758,1
99.2725269292572,60.99903099844988,1
90.54671411399852,43.39060180650027,1
34.52451385320009,60.39634245837173,0
50.2864961189907,49.80453881323059,0
49.58667721632031,59.80895099453265,0
97.64563396007767,68.86157272420604,1
32.57720016809309,95.59854761387875,0
74.24869136721598,69.82457122657193,1
71.79646205863379,78.45356224515052,1
75.3956114656803,85.75993667331619,1
35.28611281526193,47.02051394723416,0
56.25381749711624,39.26147251058019,0
30.05882244669796,49.59297386723685,0
44.66826172480893,66.45008614558913,0
66.56089447242954,41.09209807936973,0
40.45755098375164,97.53518548909936,1
49.07256321908844,51.88321182073966,0
80.27957401466998,92.11606081344084,1
66.74671856944039,60.99139402740988,1
32.72283304060323,43.30717306430063,0
64.0393204150601,78.03168802018232,1
72.34649422579923,96.22759296761404,1
60.45788573918959,73.09499809758037,1
58.84095621726802,75.85844831279042,1
99.82785779692128,72.36925193383885,1
47.26426910848174,88.47586499559782,1
50.45815980285988,75.80985952982456,1
60.45555629271532,42.50840943572217,0
82.22666157785568,42.71987853716458,0
88.9138964166533,69.80378889835472,1
94.83450672430196,45.69430680250754,1
67.31925746917527,66.58935317747915,1
57.23870631569862,59.51428198012956,1
80.36675600171273,90.96014789746954,1
68.46852178591112,85.59430710452014,1
42.0754545384731,78.84478600148043,0
75.47770200533905,90.42453899753964,1
78.63542434898018,96.64742716885644,1
52.34800398794107,60.76950525602592,0
94.09433112516793,77.15910509073893,1
90.44855097096364,87.50879176484702,1
55.48216114069585,35.57070347228866,0
74.49269241843041,84.84513684930135,1
89.84580670720979,45.35828361091658,1
83.48916274498238,48.38028579728175,1
42.2617008099817,87.10385094025457,1
99.31500880510394,68.77540947206617,1
55.34001756003703,64.9319380069486,1
74.77589300092767,89.52981289513276,1
```

Comment: can you add some example data? the code you gave doesn't really work without the data (it gives a different error and can be confusing). It's a bad idea to rely on externally-linked files as they'll eventually disappear, and then this question is impossible to understand.

Comment: @acl: Added data set.

Comment: You should probably reformulate your last follow up question as a new question.

Comment: this is a problem from Coursera, right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try something like the following.

```
bounded[Indeterminate] := $MaxMachineNumber;
bounded[x_?NumericQ] := x
```

This gives a very large number instead of `Indeterminate` so `NMinimize` keeps searching.

```
NMinimize[bounded[J[{θ0, θ1, θ2}, X1, y1]], {θ0, θ1, θ2}]    
(* {0.203498, {θ0 -> -25.1613, θ1 -> 0.206231, θ2 -> 0.201471}} *)
```

Incidentally, is there any reason you don't use `LogitModelFit`?

```
LogitModelFit[Transpose[Transpose[X1]~Join~{y1}],
    {θ0, θ1, θ2}, {θ0, θ1, θ2}, IncludeConstantBasis -> False]["BestFitParameters"]

(*{-25.1613, 0.206232, 0.201472}*)
```

**Edit:**

In response to the edits.  The only way for `Indeterminate` to arise beyond the length of `y` being zero is for the sigmoid function to return exact zero or 1.  This should never happen with real input.

```
Reduce[Sigmoid[z] == 0 || Sigmoid[z] == 1, z, Reals]

(*False *)
```

`LogitModelFit` cannot perform regularization as of version 8. You will have to do this using your `NMinimize` approach.

Comment: Could you explain a little that why when Sigmoid returns exactly 0 or 1, there will then be a `Indeterminate`?  Is it that `y_i - Sigmoid[...]` is somehow used as a denominator in the computation?

Comment: Because your cost function contains `Log[h[...]]` and `Log[1-h[...]]` If `h[...]` gives 0 or 1 one of the logs would return `Indeterminate` inside `NMinimize` since -Infinity is not a real number.

Comment: I'm still not exactly sure why converting `Indeterminate` to `$MaxMachineNumber` is safe that no $-\infty$ will not be mistakenly converted.

Comment: Because over the machine reals that `NMinmize` will try there is no instance that gives -Infinity.